# nodes iterating in cypher query of Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

in this case iam having house No's as nodes and i want to iterate them and pass them as parameter for creating relationship between people and house No's here is the code..

```
START n=node(*)
WHERE 
  HAS(n.house_no) 
RETURN n;
```

from the above i will get house no's nodes and then i want to pass them into another query

```
START 
    n=node:node_auto_index(house_no="4-10"),
    n2=node:node_auto_index(houseNo="4-10") 
WHERE 
    HAS(n.house_no) AND HAS(n2.houseNo) AND n.house_no = n2.houseNo
    create UNIQUE
    (n2)-[:LIVESIN]->(n)
    return n2.name
```

in the above query i want to pass house no's nodes property ex:house_no

How come i iterate nodes and pass a property in it as parameter..
is there any chance to combine both these queries?

can any one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameters for the index-lookup in the start clause like this:

```
START 
    n =node:node_auto_index(house_no={house_no}),
    n2=node:node_auto_index(houseNo={house_no}) 
WHERE 
    HAS(n.house_no) AND HAS(n2.house_no) AND n.house_no = n2.houseNo
CREATE UNIQUE
    (n2)-[:LIVESIN]->(n)
RETURN n2.name

and then pass a map like


{house_no:"4-10"}
```

Answer (score 2):

To combine your queries you can use `WITH`. From the [documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-with.html):

> In Cypher, the `WITH` clause is used to pipe the result from one query to the next.`

I've never tried doing index lookups based on 'piped results', would this work:

```
START n=node(*)
WHERE HAS(n.house_no)
WITH n.house_no as house_no
START n2=node:node_auto_index(houseNo=house_no)
CREATE UNIQUE n2-[:LIVESIN]->n
RETURN n2.name
```

Comment: thanks for replying..but its throwing error like..                string literal or parameter expected
"START n2=node:node_auto_index(houseNo=house_No)"